# Target path with same class as the pressed button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the fill color of an SVG path which has the same class as per the button I am clicking:

```
<button type="button" class="myClass">Click</button>
<svg id="map">
    <path class="myClass"></path>
</svg>
```

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    var cls = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#map" cls).css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});
```

Comment: `$("#map ." + cls)` - although note that none of the elements in your example have the `map` id

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, i've added the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cls` is just the class name, with no formatters.  You need to add the period.

```
$("#map ." + cls).css("fill", "#ff0000");
```